# objc_getAssociatedObject returning null

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to pass an object using `objc_setAssociatedObject`

I'm trying to pass `Evento` using the following code:

```
Evento *evento = (Evento*)[secAtt objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; 
objc_setAssociatedObject(evento, @"evento", self, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN);
```

and later I'm trying to get this `evento` with the following code:

```
Evento *evento = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, "evento");
```

It returns `nil`

EDIT: some more code:

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];

    NSString *sectionTitle = [sectionsTitles objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    NSArray *secAtt = [attractions objectForKey:sectionTitle];

    Evento *evento = (Evento*)[secAtt objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, @"evento", evento, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN);

    NSString *tipoEntretenimento = evento.entretenimento.tipo.descricao;
    NSLog(@"tipo %@", tipoEntretenimento);
    UIImageView *imgCategoria = (UIImageView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:30];
   //[imgCategoria setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
    if([tipoEntretenimento isEqualToString:@"Bares"])
        [imgCategoria setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bares.png"]];
    else if ([tipoEntretenimento isEqualToString:@"Crianca"])
        [imgCategoria setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"crianca.png"]];
    else if ([tipoEntretenimento isEqualToString:@"Guloseimas"])
        [imgCategoria setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"guloseimas.png"]];
    else if ([tipoEntretenimento isEqualToString:@"Restaurantes"])
        [imgCategoria setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"restaurantes.png"]];
    else if ([tipoEntretenimento isEqualToString:@"Teatro"])
        [imgCategoria setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"teatro.png"]];
    else if ([tipoEntretenimento isEqualToString:@"Shows"])
        [imgCategoria setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"shows"]];
    else if ([tipoEntretenimento isEqualToString:@"Dança"])
        [imgCategoria setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"danca.png"]];
    else if ([tipoEntretenimento isEqualToString:@"Concertos"])
        [imgCategoria setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"concerto.png"]];
    else if ([tipoEntretenimento isEqualToString:@"Cinema"])
        [imgCategoria setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cinema.png"]];


    UIFont *roboto = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Roboto-Bold" size:16];
    UILabel *lblNomeEvento = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:10];
    lblNomeEvento.text = evento.entretenimento.nome;
    lblNomeEvento.font = roboto;

    Agenda *agenda = nil;
    if([evento.listaAgendas count] > 0)
        agenda = (Agenda *)[evento.listaAgendas objectAtIndex:0];

    NSLog(@"agenda %@", agenda.description);

    UIImageView *imgevento = (UIImageView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:20];
    [imgevento setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
    [imgevento setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pin.png"]];

    UIButton *btnCompartilhar = (UIButton *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:40];
    [btnCompartilhar.titleLabel setHidden:YES];
    btnCompartilhar.titleLabel.text = evento.entretenimento.nome;
    [btnCompartilhar addTarget:self action:@selector(compartilharClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];


    UIButton *btnFavoritar = (UIButton *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:50];
    [btnFavoritar addTarget:self action:@selector(favoritarClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    return cell;
}
```

and later when I'm trying to get the object:

```
-(void) compartilharClick:(id)sender {
    Evento *evento = (Evento *)objc_getAssociatedObject(self, "evento");

    UIActionSheet *popup = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Compartilhar:" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancelar" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:
                            @"Facebook",
                            @"Google+",
                            @"Twitter",
                            @"Outros",
                            nil];
    popup.tag = 1;
    [popup showInView:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is probably because you are using a NSString as the key when the function needs `const void *key`

`OBJC_EXPORT void objc_setAssociatedObject(id object, const void *key, id value, objc_AssociationPolicy policy)`

Try adding `static char *EventToKey = "EventToKey";` above your implementation.

Then change your uses of `objc_getAssociatedObject` and `objc_setAssociatedObject` to

`objc_setAssociatedObject(self, EventToKey, evento, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN);`

`objc_getAssociatedObject(self, EventToKey);`

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter of `objc_setAssociatedObject` should be `self` (and the 3rd should be `evento`)

Answer (score 1):

You have `self` and `evento` mixed up when you make the association, try:

```
objc_setAssociatedObject(self, @"evento", evento, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN);
```

[Reference Link](http://nshipster.com/associated-objects/)

Edit:
The key to `objc_setAssociatedObject` (you're using "evento"), needs to be a unique pointer. If you check the reference link, they suggest use a selector as the key since it's guaranteed to be unique.

Define your key once (`char *const AssoicateKey = "evento";`) it should start working.

Also, unless you only have 1 row in your table, your code won't work. You're overwriting the association every time a cell is used. When you retrieve it, it will the object for the last cell dequeued. You can associate the object with the button and get it off the sender to your action to make it work.

Comment: Still null. Is it because I'm using ARC?

Comment: Is `secAtt` non-nil, @ladessa-ios?

Comment: Was `evento` nil when you set it? Is is the same `self`? Hard to know without more code now.

Comment: The event isn't nil when I set

Answer (score 0):

The key that you use must be the identical pointer on both calls. Not a string with the same value (if you pass "evento" twice, the pointers can be different), and most definitely one NSString* @"evento" and one C string "evento" as you did.

Easiest is to create a static variable and pass the address.